# How to delete a table row and the data is it linked with in Json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, pug

I am a beginner in NodeJs / express / axios / pug.
I am currently stuck in a spot where I need to delete a table row of data using axios.delete.

**(Supprimer means Delete)**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYhaL.png

In this image, I need to click "supprimer" and it should be deleting its row of the table and the data linked with that row in the json file.

My biggest issue is in the axios part of the code, how do i manage dynamic buttons / rows to call the axios.delete ?
If i hard code the name of the button and use the query selector to find it, it is working and it shows the message in the console : "console.log("On delete!");" but other than that, I have absolutely no idea how to get myself out of this situation.

I need to make this dynamic: `const deleteButton = document.querySelector("#deleteButton");`

to work with this: `deleteButton.addEventListener("click", event => {}`

and trigger this

```js
router.delete("/", (req, res) => {
  ███delete a row + data in json███
});
```

I am sorry if i am not clear enough, i don't know the exact words for my issues to begin with. But feel free to ask questions.

```
//█████████THIS IS THE PUG CODE FOR ADDING THE BUTTONS "DELETE"█████████\\

tr(id="row"+task.id)
    th=task.id
    td=task.title
    td=task.description
    td 
        button(id='deleteButton'+task.id class="btn btn-outline-danger" ) Supprimer
```

```js
//█████████THIS IS THE AXIOS PART FOR ADDING / DELETING USING BUTTONS█████████\\
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
  const addButton = document.querySelector("#addButton");
  const description = document.querySelector("#description");
  const title = document.querySelector("#title");
  const tableBody = document.querySelector("#tableBody");
  const deleteButton = document.querySelector("#deleteButton");

  addButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
    axios
      .post("/tasks", {
        title: title.value,
        description: description.value
      })
      .then(res => {
        tableBody.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", res.data);
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });

  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
    axios
      .delete("/tasks", {})
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
});
```

```js
//█████████THIS IS THE CODE TRIGGERED BY THE BUTTON CLICKED (add or delete)█████████\\
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  newID = currentID[0].id + 1;
  //console.log(newID);

  const newTask = {
    id: newID,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description
  };
  const updateID = {
    id: 55
  };

  res.render("includes/task", { task: newTask });

  tasks.push(newTask);

  fs.readFile(pathDuFichier, "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("File read failed:", err);
      return;
    }

    jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    jsonData.task.push(newTask);
    jsonData.compteur[0].id = newID;
    json = JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4);
    console.log(json);


    fs.writeFile(pathDuFichier, json, err => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error writing file", err);
      } else {
        console.log("Successfully wrote file" + json);
      }
    });
  });

  //---------------------------------------------

  //██████████████████████████████████████████████████████


});

router.delete("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("On delete!");
});
```

```
//█████████THIS IS THE ACTUAL JSON FILE I HAVE█████████\\

{
  "task": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Balayeuse",
      "description": "Passer la balayeuse demain"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Plancher",
      "description": "Laver le plancher ce soir"
    }
  ],
  "compteur": [
    {
      "id": 14
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is this `███` ?

Comment: @MisterJojo those are alt+219 characters, they are thick and makes it easier to make a line